# Android Facebook deep linking bug(!?)

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

I've implemented app deep linking on android, by configuring all the FB stuff.
And also I have a Facebook flash application.
All works fine except one case.
When I go into FB FanPage in the FB app, and press  `https://apps.facebook.com/app_url` link, it opens in default browser, instead of launching the app. Is it a bug?

PS:
Same configuration is working for IOS app. That link is launching the app.